# Will Stack Exchange ever put zero reputation gain on question votes?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions

I'm the first to admit, I'm an asker, not an answerer.
I totally get that [you want pearls](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), and that's fine.

But this trend has me thinking - will you ever decide that because answers are so much more important than questions, questions upvotes should generate zero rep gain? And then perhaps do a rep recalc?

Comment: Don't forget that (most) askers will turn into answerers sooner or later.

Comment: @Gamecat: [Ahem...](http://stackoverflow.com/users/39677/blankman)

Answer (score 16):

I certainly hope not.  Reputation is awarded for contributing to the community, and the community is enriched both by good answers and by good questions.  Both should be encouraged.

Answer (score 8):

My crystal ball says.....

### No

Comment: Nice, a talking crystal ball.

Comment: I'm looking into my magic 8-ball but it's just black.

Comment: this post is flagged as low-quality

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it would be a good thing to not award rep for a well written question.  Assuming that people are upvoting well written, interesting questions and not upvoting poorly asked questions, the people who take the time to ask good questions deserve the rep.

Answer (score 1):

A rep recalc is definitely not going to happen because such a thing would punish people who earned reputation by asking good questions - this discourages participation in the community and is only justified in really drastic cases (e.g. if somebody inflated his reputation score by using a bug in the system). Whatever reputation you gained is yours now, it cannot be taken from you retroactively.

I can imagine the question score to be lowered even further however, particularly for people with many questions and no answers. After all, the system is supposed to encourage people take their new knowledge and give it back. But I don't see it ever dropping to zero - there really are good and bad questions and the former need to be encouraged somehow. Not to mention encouraging people asking good questions to stay with the community even if they don't have enough experience to answer questions yet.